# 3ds max export model in stl format

Tags: stl, export, 3dsmax

I would like to export the model I have in 3ds max to stl format.
Very easy so far.
But I would like to rotate and move my model a bit and when exporting the model to stl format the stl data file should reflect rotation and translation but it doesn't.
It seems that regardless of what I'm doing with the model in 3ds max, the stl export file contains the original coordinates of the faces.

What can I do? Does any know how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply xForm modifier to the object and use it to transform your model. 
*This would change the vertex co-ordinates with respect to the pivot and you should be able to export this edited geometry.*